# Should we combine correct answers?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accepted-answer

In [How can a contract run itself at a later time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/42/131), there are two answers which each capture roughly half of the answer.

They should be combined, but I don't want to steal anyone's rep, or anything.

Obviously I should cite the other answers, but is there anything I should be aware of before I add an answer combing the two?

Comment: One of the answers has been made a community wiki, thus solving the issue. This question is still pertinent for future reference, I think.

Comment: Does it devalue the reward point system? I.e. if we combine - or quote from one person, will it reduce their potential of being upvoted?

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed on the main Meta.SE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140345/joining-multiple-answers-into-one-single-answer).

The general consensus is no, leave them separate.  Although the case you mention, which is now community wiki, leaves the way open to merge if this community sees fit.